# Cyclic calling of object form one class to another

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, class

I have ClassA and ClassB. Now i want to call a method of ClassA in ClassB.So i imported ClassA in ClassB and created an object of it and called that method.Now i want to call method of classB in classA. How can i do that.

Comment: This seems a bit naughty to me. This would mean the two classes are somewhat coupled. Have you looked into using protocols etc?

Comment: create a separate class and this class write both method and then call whenever you want.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with doing this per se, and the pattern does occur. You need to say what you tried and what didn't work as the simple answer is you call B from A in the same way you called A from B.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your fundamental issue is a cyclic import. The answer to this is stop importing in your header file. If ClassA needs to call something from ClassB, then `#import "ClassB.h"` should be added to `ClassA.m`, *not* to `ClassA.h`. Same thing if ClassB needs to call something in ClassA. If ClassA needs to reference ClassB in its header (e.g. a property of type ClassB) then you can forward-declare the class using

```
@class ClassB;
```

at the top of your `ClassA.h`. This tells the compiler that there exists a class named `ClassB`, and that you will tell it what that class is at some later time.